# Is there an efficient way to split a string into a list with numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

So I have created a code that will take a bunch of random values from an already created list, the list is 100000 values long, so that I can really test the power. In the list that I create I use a random 2 characters to put between each value. The example code is shown before, and please note that this is done before the code using numba is used.

```
 lister = []
    for i in range(0,100000):
        day = i*5
        hour = i*8
        slope = i*9
        price = i*6
        volume = i
        percentage = i*2
        time = datetime.now()
        time = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
        lister.append(str(day)+'**'+str(hour)+'**'+str(slope)+'**'+str(price)+'**'+str(volume)+'**'+str(percentage)+'**'+str(time))

 npList = np.array(dictionary)
```

Then I run the npDictthrough a function calling numba multiple times because the first time I am aware that it compiles it before hand, but the second time is still slower than when I use it without numba. I think that the problem is that I split the string into a list. This is my code for the numba function:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def returnDayGrab(lister):
    times = np.zeros_like(lister)
    hours = np.zeros_like(lister)
    slopes = np.zeros_like(lister)
    prices = np.zeros_like(lister)
    volumes = np.zeros_like(lister)
    percentages = np.zeros_like(lister)
    for ii, item in enumerate(lister):
        #list2 = np.fromstring(item, dtype=str, sep='**')
        #list2 = np.array(item.split('**'))
        list2 = item.split('**')
        times[ii] = list2[0]
        hours[ii] = list2[1]
        slopes[ii] = list2[2]
        prices[ii] = list2[3]
        volumes[ii] = list2[4]
        percentages[ii] = list2[5]
    
    return times, hours, slopes, prices, volumes, percentages
```

The way I run my code is to show the two differences in times. As shown below.

```
    now1 = datetime.now()
    times, hours, slopes, prices, volumes, percentages = returnDayGrab(npDict)
    now2 = datetime.now()
    print(now2-now1)
    now1 = datetime.now()
    times, hours, slopes, prices, volumes, percentages = returnDayGrab(npDict)
    now2 = datetime.now()
    print(now2-now1)
```

This is my result with using numba:

```
0:00:03.217734
0:00:00.938417
```

This is the result when the numba decorator is taken out:

```
0:00:00.190655
0:00:00.203312
```

As you can see both go's of the numba decorator being gone it is faster. The reason, as I mentioned before, that I think it is the split function that slows it down is because when in my code that utilizes numba if instead of splitting the item, I just set each list equal to the item, like this:

```
times[ii] = item
hours[ii] = item
slopes[ii] = item
prices[ii] = item
volumes[ii] = item
percentages[ii] = item
```

This is the result utilizing numba:

```
0:00:00.108041
0:00:00.048682
```

this is the result without numba:

```
0:00:00.213311
0:00:00.230100
```

So without using the split function numba is significantly faster. I was wondering if there was an efficient way to split the string into a list, or if there is another fast alternative. As you can see from my commented out code I have already tried `np.fromstring(item, dtype=str, sep='**')` and I have tried `np.array(item.split('**'))` to follow the speed of numpy.

Comment: You will find that lists are not great for numba because they are just pointers to different parts of memory. One of the key features of numba is to try to be smart about bringing values into memory, however this is not easy with lists. Also it appears like you are using individual values from the arrays, which will also be difficult to optimize.

I don't know about a better method for splitting the string, but if you are concerned with performance, you will want to be careful about how you choose your datatypes. You can put strings into numpy arrays, which may improve your performance.

Comment: I agree, the only problem is that I have no control over how the list is given to me, it is given to my code in exactly that format. The reason it was done like that is because the list is supposed to come from a nested multiprocessor nested dictionary that uses strings to be nested. I'm hoping to find a better way for either.

Comment: did you ever solved this? splitting string inside numba?

Comment: From what I remember, I just figured it out to make the list in terms of 7, and just mathematically was able to figure out which index was the day, month, year, etc based on the current index of the list. Hopefully you can do that too, otherwise sorry no. Your best bet might just be to write your code in C or C++. C++ is a generally pretty easy and straight forward language especially good for data science in my experience.